# Get image details ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

How to I get details of images from all folders and sub folders with ImageMagick in this format.

```
file-name file-location file-format size width height
```

PS - I have read this page http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php but cannot find how to get file location path and how to include files in sub folders .

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure ImageMagick won't work recursively like that by itself. You'll need to write a script/program around it to work through your directory structure and call it once per file you want to check.

Comment: Ok . What about getting the file location ? Do you know how to do that ? I searched for recursive image scripts but found only for Linux . I am on Windows .

Comment: Search for something like "windows command prompt list files recursively" and you'll find plenty of information.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will return the information you are looking for:

```
  identify -format "%f %d %m %b %w %h\n" ./* ./*/*
```

1. The escape sequence for the file directory is `%d`.
2. To include all files in the current folder, use `./*` (the shell wildcard).
3. To include all files in all sub folders, use `./*/*` (shell wildcards).

(You didn't tell which operating system you are on. The above will work for Linux, Unix and Mac OS X. For Windows, use `.\*.*` and `.\*.*\*.*` as wild cards.)

***Attention!***, if you have non-image files or PDF documents in your folders, this command could run for quite a long time. Non-image files will produce an error message like

```
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `EXE' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

This can be avoided by re-directing all error messages to `/dev/null`.

So it may be better to use this variant:

```
 identify                                   \
   -format "%f %d %m %b %w %h\n"            \
    *.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,png,tif,tiff,ppm,gif}   \
    */*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,png,tif,tiff,ppm,gif} \
   2>/dev/null
```

Here is an example from Mac OS X:

```
delta.jpg #12649876 JPEG 17441B 307 205
CMYK_separation_–_maximum_black.jpg #21270389 JPEG 1453360B 1600 4780
HFnCz.jpg #21270389 JPEG 356748B 1600 1195
combined.jpg #21270389 JPEG 528221B 1600 1195
res.jpg #26408022 JPEG 57546B 603 300
red-500x2000.jpg #26951336 JPEG 6288B 500 2000
resized-red-2000x2000.jpg #26951336 JPEG 7430B 1000 1000
big-edge-25.jpg #27290574 JPEG 98916B 1024 288
big.jpg #27290574 JPEG 19216B 1024 576
double.jpg #27290574 JPEG 35076B 480 270
small.jpg #27290574 JPEG 20716B 720 404
```

(Yes, I did run this command in a directory which has subdirectories named `#27290574`, `#26951336` and similar....)

You may want to get the output look more table-like. For this, pipe the results through `column -t`. Try this then:

```
 identify                                   \
   -format "%f %d %m %b %w %h\n"            \
    *.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,png,tif,tiff,ppm,gif}   \
    */*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,png,tif,tiff,ppm,gif} \
   2>/dev/null  |  column -t
```

Result in my case:

```
delta.jpg                            #12649876  JPEG  17441B    307   205
CMYK_separation_–_maximum_black.jpg  #21270389  JPEG  1453360B  1600  4780
HFnCz.jpg                            #21270389  JPEG  356748B   1600  1195
combined.jpg                         #21270389  JPEG  528221B   1600  1195
res.jpg                              #26408022  JPEG  57546B    603   300
red-500x2000.jpg                     #26951336  JPEG  6288B     500   2000
resized-red-2000x2000.jpg            #26951336  JPEG  7430B     1000  1000
big-edge-25.jpg                      #27290574  JPEG  98916B    1024  288
big.jpg                              #27290574  JPEG  19216B    1024  576
double.jpg                           #27290574  JPEG  35076B    480   270
small.jpg                            #27290574  JPEG  20716B    720   404
```